# Thumbnail grid with occasional large image

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to create a grid of thumbnails and I wanted to add some uniqueness to the design by formatting every *th picture as a larger image.  Now, I understand the photo would have to match grid spacing to look right.

But I can't seem to figure out how I could get the thumbnails to fill in the empty spaces created when changing an image size arbitrarily. Does it lie in css position settings?  Do the larger images have to be positioned after the thumbnail-grid is made using absolute positioning?

You can take a look at what I mean here: http://ryandury.com/photos/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the site that you gave as an example, there is a formation of One big picture then 3 rows of 5 smaller pictures and another row below it of 6 small pictures. and it goes on and on. now this is just the formation of the page.

can you please give a better description for that thing you want to do with thumbnails.